# Cache em sistemas Web

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, cache

Tenho um sistema web utilizando Ajax que é constantemente atualizado. Preciso implementar uma forma de atualizar o cache do usuário de arquivos .js e .css quando esses arquivos são modificados.

Tentei resolver de duas formas. A primeira é a utilização de url com variável para chamar esses arquivos obrigando o navegador a buscar sempre os recursos e não utilizar o cache, mas dessa forma o sistema ficou lento por não contar com os benefícios do cache.

A outra forma foi com o cache manifest do html5 com scripts para criar dinamicamente o manifest. Mas como o sistema tem upload de imagens constante, cada vez que uma imagem é upada o manifest é atualizado para uma nova versão, obrigando a renovação do cache dos usuários para todos os arquivos.

Existe uma forma de utilizar o cache normalmente tal qual ele funciona, mas quando houver alteração de arquivos .js e .css, que seja informado ao browser os arquivos a serem renovados no cache, a partir de um controle de versão? Alguém conhece uma abordagem que funcione mais ou menos assim?

Comment: Olá Rafael Pedroso, a comunidade do stackoverflow busca responder perguntas específicas. Nós não respondemos com base em nossas opiniões. Peço que formate melhor sua pergunta para que se torne específica com um problema que você está tendo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma abordagem simples é versionar o js e css de acordo com a versão do deploy. Ex.:

```
<?php 
    define( 'VERSAO', '1.0.0' );    
    echo '<script src="https://example.com/arquivo.js?ver='.VERSAO.'" />';
?>
```

Assim ele vai fazer o cache sempre com a tag de versionamento. Enquanto a tag continuar a mesma o navegador não vai buscar novamente o arquivo. Quando precisar buscar novamente os arquivos você atualiza a constante `VERSAO` e todos os arquivos vão ser buscados e cacheados de novo.

Ex.:

[image: screenshot desta tela mostrando um arquivo CSS com uma varável GET sendo buscado no cache do navegador]

Comment: Oi Ricardo, se eu passar uma variável GET (ver='.VERSAO.') na requisição do .js, o navegador não vai fazer cache do arquivo, pois ele entende que é um arquivo dinâmico.

Comment: @RafaelPedroso, você está enganado. Veja no print o console aqui mesmo do SO com uma variável GET no arquivo css sendo buscado no cache do meu navegador: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zsyf57e1ewoy5y7/Captura%20de%20tela%202017-02-21%2012.26.17_Ink_LI-cache.jpg?dl=0

Comment: sugiro ler esse artigo https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/appcache/beginner/ talvez ajude

Comment: Entendi @RicardoMoraleida. Não sei porque no meu sistema não se comporta assim. Vou investigar isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variável time() como parâmetro para não precisar alterar o código cada vez que atualizar o CSS/JS

```
<?php
    echo "<script src='seuJavascript.js?time=".time()."'/>"
?>
```